# Is this an effect or a type of font?

Tags: fonts, typography, effects, website-design

I have seen a lot this type of fonts (the ones in the bar). It is a relief effect or the font is just like that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an effect applied with either a graphics program like photoshop, or done dynamically with css for webpages.

Comment: Here are a list of tutorials for how to get this effect using css, photoshop, illustrator and a few others:
http://sixrevisions.com/graphics-design/10-wonderful-letterpress-type-tutorials/

Comment: Yep. Fonts themselves do not support any colour or shade variation (although it is possible to fake it with multiple layered fonts, or halftoning effects).

Answer (score 4):

It is simply a **white drop shadow** applied to the text.

In this case, it is achieved with the CSS code:

```
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
```

Works best on bold text.

The icons would probably have been done in Photoshop in a similar style to match.  In Photoshop, you could get the same effect by duplicating the text, moving the duplicate down one pixel, dropping it to a layer underneath, and making it white.

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way in photoshop since photoshop has layer style called drop-shadow, but if I did this with code, I would probably use the latter method with js to get cross browser relief effect, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/WVnZL/  -- `text-shadow` support is horrible http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-textshadow

Comment: `text-shadow` support is actually pretty good.  All the modern browser versions support it, and the more recent versions of everything but IE support is as well.

Comment: I'd favour `text-shadow` over the text-doubling javascript. Many screenreaders ([98%, apparently](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2011/javascript-and-screenreaders/)) support javascript, and it can't be fun for these people to listen to every menu item twice. Text shadow will rarely be *essential* to a design, so I'd say use it as a progressive enhancement: site looks better in non-IE, still looks good and is perfectly usable in IE.